# Why don' t I get an output from this 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build an 2D array with the size of from 1D array and pupolate it with random numbers. Why don't I get an output when I run this code below? There is no errors in my IDE:

```
public void raggedArray(){
    int maxRows = 3;
    int maxCols = 4;

    int [] onedArray = new int [maxRows];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++){
        onedArray[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * 100) * maxCols);
    }

    int [][] twodArray = new int[maxRows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++){
        twodArray[i] = new int[onedArray[i]];
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < twodArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < twodArray[i].length; j++){
            twodArray[i][j] = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        }
    }

    System.out.println("2 - The 2D array: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < twodArray.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < twodArray[i].length; j++){
            System.out.print(twodArray[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

        }


}
```

Comment: I get output. I get lots of output of random numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code compiles correctly, runs and outputs some numbers. Maybe `raggedArray()` isn't called like [Giacomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/671092/giacomo) mentioned?

It might also be that the two-dimensional array is created incorrectly. I suppose this:

```
twodArray[i] = new int[onedArray[i]];
```

should be replaced with:

```
twodArray[i] = new int[maxCols];
```

Answer (score 1):

I just copied your code .. compiled it , ran it and got it to print something .. not really sure what we are trying to do here, but it does print something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the code does, and if it's correct or not, but it should print something, absolutely. At least `System.out.println("2 - The 2D array: ");` is guaranteed to be executed.

**Are you sure `raggedArray()` is ever called?**

Are you sure you're looking to the right spot in your IDE? Try without the IDE, running the code from a terminal.

Comment: hmmm. Stupid me. Sorry for bothering you :-)